# why i am not able to get innerHTML of following code snippet

Tags: jquery

I have div with id "divDesc0".

I want to fetch innerHTML or body of first div inside it.

This is my html code-

```
<div class="row" id="divDesc0">
   <div class="col-sm-1 text-right">
    <p>jk m</p>
   </div>
   <div> 
     <span class="button" id="deldivDesc0" onclick="removeSegment(this.id)">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
     </span> 
   </div>
</div>
```

**I tried following but not working**

```
$("#divDesc0 > div:first").attr("innerHTML")
```

but getting *undefined*

Comment: `innerHTML` is not a attribute,  Use `$("#divDesc0 > div:first").html()` or `$("#divDesc0 > div:first").prop("innerHTML")`

Comment: `$("#divDesc0 > div:first).html()`  or `$("#divDesc0 > div:first).text()`

Comment: user8756809  did you checked answer?

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's how [meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) then return here and do the same with the tick/checkmark till it turns green. This informs the community, a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. *Welcome to Stack!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Element.innerHTML` is a [property of a DOM element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), and hence it is not part of attributes accessible by [jQuery's `.attr()` method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) (although traditionally it might be). This distinction was made in jQuery v1.6 and above:

> As of jQuery 1.6, the `.prop()` method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while `.attr()` retrieves attributes.
>
> For example, `selectedIndex`, `tagName`, `nodeName`, `nodeType`, `ownerDocument`, `defaultChecked`, and `defaultSelected` should be retrieved and set with the .prop() method.

Therefore, you have the following options:

1. Use [jQuery's `.html()` method](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to return the innerHTML of a **jQuery object**, i.e.:

   ```
   $('#divDesc0 > div:first').html()
   ```
2. Retrieve the underlying DOM node and access its `.innerHTML` property, i.e.:

   ```
   $('#divDesc0 > div:first')[0].innerHTML
   ```
3. Access the `innerHTML` property directly on the jQuery object using [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), i.e.:

   ```
   $('#divDesc0 > div:first').prop('innerHTML');
   ```

Comment: Use `.prop()` for accessing properties

Comment: @Satpal Yes, that is another alternative. Thanks for highlighting that!

Comment: Thanks terry, it solved my problem.I am really new to this,so i have a doubt what is really the difference between 'property' and 'attribute'.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

change `.attr("innerHTML")` to `.prop("innerHTML")`

as `innerHTML` is not an attribute.

fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/rz8ebf6e/**

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use just `text()`

```js
var a=$('#divDesc0 > div:first').text();
alert(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="divDesc0">
   <div class="col-sm-1 text-right">
    <p>jk m</p>
   </div>
   <div> 
     <span class="button" id="deldivDesc0" onclick="removeSegment(this.id)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></span> 
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because `.text()` does not return any HTML tags in it, but simply the textContent of a node.